# pymysql.err.OperationalError: (1130, '172.18.0.3' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mariadb

I have a dockerized app and use the following docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
    app:
        restart: always
        build: ./app
        ports:
            - "8501:8501"
        env_file:
            - .env
        command: streamlit run Main.py
        networks:
            - streamlit_network

    mariadb:
        image: mariadb:10.5.17
        ports:
             - "3306:3306"
        volumes:
            - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
            - db_conf:/etc/mysql/conf.d
        environment:
              MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "root"
              MYSQL_DATABASE: "db"
              MYSQL_USER: "user"
              MYSQL_PASSWORD: "password"
        networks:
            - streamlit_network
    nginx:
        restart: always
        build: ./nginx
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        depends_on:
            - app
            - mariadb
        networks:
           - streamlit_network
volumes:
    db_data:
    db_conf:
networks:
    streamlit_network:
        driver: bridge
```

I am able to access mysql using the following commands:

```
mysql -h <ip-address where database is hosted> -p -u username database
```

inside of my ubuntu machine which has a host IP of
How do I achieve the same within docker container

I believe '172.18.0.3' is a randomly generated ip address by docker as the IP address did change to '172.18.0.2' on another occasion.

The .env file is:

```
host="mariadb"
user="user"
password="password"
database="db"
port="3306"
```

This is the trace for mariadb when I am running `docker-compose up`:

```
mariadb_1  | 2022-10-27 12:20:24+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MariaDB Server 1:10.9.3+maria~ubu2204 started.
mariadb_1  | 2022-10-27 12:20:25+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
mariadb_1  | 2022-10-27 12:20:25+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MariaDB Server 1:10.9.3+maria~ubu2204 started.
mariadb_1  | 2022-10-27 12:20:26+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: MariaDB upgrade information missing, assuming required
mariadb_1  | 2022-10-27 12:20:26+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: MariaDB upgrade (mariadb-upgrade) required, but skipped due to $MARIADB_AUTO_UPGRADE setting
mariadb_1  | 2022-10-27 12:20:26 0 [Note] mariadbd (server 10.9.3-MariaDB-1:10.9.3+maria~ubu2204) starting as process 1 ...
mariadb_1  | 2022-10-27 12:20:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
mariadb_1  | 2022-10-27 12:20:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of transaction pools: 1
mariadb_1  | 2022-10-27 12:20:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
mariadb_1  | 2022-10-27 12:20:26 0 [Note] mariadbd: O_TMPFILE is not supported on /tmp (disabling future attempts)
mariadb_1  | 2022-10-27 12:20:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128.000MiB, chunk size = 2.000MiB
mariadb_1  | 2022-10-27 12:20:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
mariadb_1  | 2022-10-27 12:20:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: File system buffers for log disabled (block size=512 bytes)
mariadb_1  | 2022-10-27 12:20:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segments are active.
mariadb_1  | 2022-10-27 12:20:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12.000MiB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
mariadb_1  | 2022-10-27 12:20:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12.000MiB.
mariadb_1  | 2022-10-27 12:20:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: log sequence number 35204; transaction id 8
mariadb_1  | 2022-10-27 12:20:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
mariadb_1  | 2022-10-27 12:20:27 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
mariadb_1  | 2022-10-27 12:20:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 221027 12:20:27
mariadb_1  | 2022-10-27 12:20:27 0 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table: "Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist". Some plugins may be not loaded
mariadb_1  | 2022-10-27 12:20:28 0 [Warning] You need to use --log-bin to make --expire-logs-days or --binlog-expire-logs-seconds work.
mariadb_1  | 2022-10-27 12:20:28 0 [ERROR] Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.servers' doesn't exist
mariadb_1  | 2022-10-27 12:20:28 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
mariadb_1  | 2022-10-27 12:20:28 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
mariadb_1  | 2022-10-27 12:20:28 0 [ERROR] Missing system table mysql.proxies_priv; please run mysql_upgrade to create it
mariadb_1  | 2022-10-27 12:20:28 0 [ERROR] Missing system table mysql.roles_mapping; please run mysql_upgrade to create it
mariadb_1  | 2022-10-27 12:20:28 0 [Warning] Can't open and lock time zone table: Table 'mysql.time_zone_leap_second' doesn't exist trying to live without them
mariadb_1  | 2022-10-27 12:20:28 0 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.func table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
mariadb_1  | 2022-10-27 12:20:28 0 [ERROR] Cannot open mysql.event
mariadb_1  | 2022-10-27 12:20:28 0 [ERROR] mariadbd: Event Scheduler: An error occurred when initializing system tables. Disabling the Event Scheduler.
mariadb_1  | 2022-10-27 12:20:28 1 [Warning] Failed to load slave replication state from table mysql.gtid_slave_pos: 1146: Table 'mysql.gtid_slave_pos' doesn't exist
mariadb_1  | 2022-10-27 12:20:28 0 [Note] mariadbd: ready for connections.
mariadb_1  | Version: '10.9.3-MariaDB-1:10.9.3+maria~ubu2204'  socket: '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
mariadb_1  | 2022-10-27 12:27:27 3 [Warning] Aborted connection 3 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '172.18.0.2' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
mariadb_1  | 2022-10-27 12:35:05 4 [Warning] Aborted connection 4 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '172.18.0.2' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
```

Comment: `host="mariadb"` is correct for a connection between containers; you do not need to know the host IP address.  If you're getting an "access denied" error then the network-level wiring is correct and you are successfully making a TCP connection to the database.

Comment: you can reference the mariadb within the same bridge network using either the service name(which is *mariadb*) or on *localhost* on port 3306.

Comment: @rebelution where exactly do I do that? I have host="mariadb" under the .env file which is used by the app for reading from the database.

Comment: yes, that's correct assumption